# Socket.io - emitting JS object causes max-recursion error, then doesn't send at all

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io

I have an object that stores two other objects. When sending this specific object to the server for the first time since the page was last loaded, I get this error:

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
at Function.[Symbol.hasInstance] (<anonymous>)
at r (socket.io.js:1)
at r (socket.io.js:1)
at r (socket.io.js:1)
at r (socket.io.js:1)
at r (socket.io.js:1)
at r (socket.io.js:1)
at r (socket.io.js:1)
at r (socket.io.js:1)
at r (socket.io.js:1)
```

I have googled for possible answers, and I have tried sending other objects that aren't so large, which works just fine.

Also, once the error has been thrown, sending the object again, sends the object, but isn't received. I have no idea how to approach this.

The Object I am trying to send is:

```
data {
    p1: {
        name: "Player 1",
        obj: {
            angle:0,
            dir:0,
            health:100,
            name:"Player 1",
            pos:p5.Vector {p5: p5, x: 0, y: 0, z: 0},
            projectiles:[],
            show: {
                noStroke();
                fill(255);

                for (let i in this.projectiles) { this.projectiles[i].show() }

                push();
                translate(this.pos.x, this.pos.y);
                rotate(PI - this.angle);
                imageMode(CENTER);
                image(pgraphic, 0, 0, this.health / 2, this.health / 2);
                pop();
            }
            update: function () {
                if (this.useControls) {
                if (keyIsDown(68))
                this.angle -= 0.125;
                else if (keyIsDown(65))
                this.angle += 0.125;

                if (keyIsDown(87)) {
                this.dir = 1;
                } else if (keyIsDown(83)) {
                this.dir = -1;
                } else if (!keyIsDown(87) && !keyIsDown(83))
                this.dir = 0;

                if (keyIsDown(32))
                this.shoot()

                this.pos.x += ((this.health / 10) * sin(this.angle)) * this.dir;
                this.pos.y += ((this.health / 10) * cos(this.angle)) * this.dir;

                this.pos.x = constrain(this.pos.x, 0 - width / 2, width / 2);
                this.pos.y = constrain(this.pos.y, 0 - height / 2, height / 2);

                for (let i in this.projectiles) {
                this.projectiles[i].update()

                if (this.projectiles[i].pos.x <= 0 - (width / 2) || 
                this.projectiles[i].pos.x >= (width / 2) || 
                this.projectiles[i].pos.y <= 0 - ((height / 2) * 1.5) || 
                this.projectiles[i].pos.y >= (height / 2)) {
                this.projectiles.splice(i, 1)
                }}}
            }
            useControls:true,
            vel:p5.Vector {p5: p5, x: 0, y: 0, z: 0},
        }
    },
    p2: {
        name: "Player 2",
        obj: {
            angle:0,
            dir:0,
            health:100,
            name:"Player 2",
            pos:p5.Vector {p5: p5, x: 0, y: 0, z: 0},
            projectiles:[],
            show: {
                noStroke();
                fill(255);

                for (let i in this.projectiles) { this.projectiles[i].show() }

                push();
                translate(this.pos.x, this.pos.y);
                rotate(PI - this.angle);
                imageMode(CENTER);
                image(pgraphic, 0, 0, this.health / 2, this.health / 2);
                pop();
            }
            update: function () {
                if (this.useControls) {
                if (keyIsDown(68))
                this.angle -= 0.125;
                else if (keyIsDown(65))
                this.angle += 0.125;

                if (keyIsDown(87)) {
                this.dir = 1;
                } else if (keyIsDown(83)) {
                this.dir = -1;
                } else if (!keyIsDown(87) && !keyIsDown(83))
                this.dir = 0;

                if (keyIsDown(32))
                this.shoot()

                this.pos.x += ((this.health / 10) * sin(this.angle)) * this.dir;
                this.pos.y += ((this.health / 10) * cos(this.angle)) * this.dir;

                this.pos.x = constrain(this.pos.x, 0 - width / 2, width / 2);
                this.pos.y = constrain(this.pos.y, 0 - height / 2, height / 2);

                for (let i in this.projectiles) {
                this.projectiles[i].update()

                if (this.projectiles[i].pos.x <= 0 - (width / 2) || 
                this.projectiles[i].pos.x >= (width / 2) || 
                this.projectiles[i].pos.y <= 0 - ((height / 2) * 1.5) || 
                this.projectiles[i].pos.y >= (height / 2)) {
                this.projectiles.splice(i, 1)
                }}}
            }
            useControls:true,
            vel:p5.Vector {p5: p5, x: 0, y: 0, z: 0},
        }
    }
}
```

this is only a small portion of what I am attempting to send, however, this is the part that is causing the error.

full code on [GitHub](https://github.com/KlaussMC/Socket-Game)

Comment: So, does the object has cyclic references (eg, parent/child/root relation as properties?) Any chance you could describe the objects' structure you are trying to send?

Comment: I'm using 'this.' several times, but other than that, I don't think so

Comment: Without seeing the object you are sending, there is nothing to answer on your question, except to ponder what might be the reason. Please provider more info about the structure you wish to send

Answer (score 5):

I figured out what the problem was: this error only occurs when sending instances of classes. By extracting the data from once instance and sending it via standard JavaScript object-literal, then reapplying the data to a separate instance will do the trick.